# How to return all powerpivot rows with at least one match for a given non-index key

Tags: excel-2010, powerpivot

I have a table of user accounts, with an account ID, and a name. Layout simplified as:

```
ID    |    Provider    |  AccountName  |   Value1  |
10043 |  Provider 1    |      XX       |    7      |
10056 |  Provider 2    |     John      |    45     |
10185 |  Provider 1    |     John      |    8      |
10015 |  Provider 2    |     Mark      |     52
```

These aren't directly linked. In PowerPivot, I am looking to output a pivot table of all users which have at least one account with Provider 1, with their values e.g.

```
ID    |    Provider    |  AccountName  |   Value1  |
10043 |  Provider 1    |      XX       |    7      |
10056 |  Provider 2    |     John      |    45     |
10185 |  Provider 1    |     John      |    8      |
```

Basically I want to filter the table to only AccountNames which have an account with Provider 1.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This measure will give a TRUE result for each row of the table that contains an account name which uses Provider 1 somewhere in the table:

```
Provider_1_Accounts:=CONTAINS(FILTER(ALL('Table1'),[Provider]="Provider 1"),[AccountName],FIRSTNONBLANK('Table1'[AccountName],[AccountName]))
```

If you wrap it in an IF to return 1s and BLANKS like this:

```
Provider_1_Accounts:=IF(CONTAINS(FILTER(ALL('Table1'),[Provider]="Provider 1"),[AccountName],FIRSTNONBLANK('Table1'[AccountName],[AccountName])),1,BLANK())
```

Then this can be used in the Values field of your Pivot Table and all the other fields can be added to the rows, shown in tabular form with no totals:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this is along the lines of what I attempted. I created a calculated column showing a version of the formula above, then put this in a slicer.